# Change the web version of an email / change a URL?

Tags: civimail

Example:
Sent email, included wrong link and some wrong text.  Too late to change email - but is it possible to change the URL direction or change the text for the browser version?

Latest Drupal 7 and CiviCRM

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing the URL to redirect elsewhere is something that happens outside of CiviCRM.  If you have click-through tracking enabled, you could also *probably* change the URL in `civicrm_mailing_trackable_url` in the database, but I've never tried this.

Comment: Just did that - it worked. 
Also went into civicrm_mailing and made a few changes - worked.
Thanks!

Comment: What changes in `civicrm_mailing`, for the benefit of future readers?

Comment: Well the complaint department was upset when they clicked: View in Browser - it still showed the wrong text. (also apparently they forwarded the link to view our e-blast to their employees) So now - the view in browser displays the correct information.